# TBBS required for Component Template and Page Template to implement SiteEdit for Component with component links

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am working on Dreamweaver templating in Tridion 2011 SP1 and SiteEdit 2012.

My component has component links. I want to enable SitEdit for the component links too.

I wrote a Component Template to get the values from linked component and referred it in Main Component Template building block.

My main component CT has following template building blocks.

```
Dreamweaver TBB(Referring to Component link CT internally)
Enable Inline Editing for the Component
Default Finish Actions.
```

Page TBB is like this

```html
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      @@RenderComponentPresentation("ComponentID","ComponentTemplateID")@@
   </body>
</html>
```

Page Template has following blocks:

```
Page TBB
Enable Inline Editing for the Page
Default Finish Actions
```

I am able to see the SiteEdit tags when I previewed the Page. I am also able to see the content from the Component links.

But when I published the Page I am unable edit the content.

Do I need to add any Template Building Blocks or any modification in any block?

Comment: There is no such thing as SiteEdit 2012. Which version are you using? If you don't know, you can look it up in the "Programs" applet in the Windows Control Panel.

Comment: Are you browsing the staging site through the SiteEdit proxy?

Comment: I am browsing the page through site edit proxy.I am using Tridion 2012 UI.

Comment: If you're using Tridion UI 2012, then why are you using the proxy? The proxy is for 2009, no need to use it anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But when I published the Page I am unable edit the Content.

Is your Publication Target correctly configured for Tridion UI 2012 (**not** SiteEdit!)

What do you mean with "I am unable edit the Content"?

- You don't see the SDL Tridion button on the top left corner?
- You seen the button but clicking it results in an error?
- You see the borders for you component presentations but the fields are not editable?

Did you also add the "Enable inline Editing for Components" TBB in your Component Presentations?

Comment: I am able to see the borders for the component presentations. I enabled inline editing for the component presentations. But the content is not editable there in UI. Thank you.

Comment: Check the HTML markup around the fields. If there's no HTML markup, then you're possibly not using @@RenderComponentField@@